# How to generate ListnerCertificate CertificateArn in loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate, ssl-certificate, aws-cloudformation, troposphere

I want to add `certificate` in `listner` of `ApplicationLoadBalancer`. How can i add and how can i associate with each ther, I am using `HTTPS` protocol for that i need to set/configure sslcertificate.

```
Listener = t.add_resource(elb.Listener(
    "Listener",
    Certificates=elb.Certificate(
        CertificateArn="",
    ),
    Port="443",
    Protocol="HTTPS",
    LoadBalancerArn=Ref(ApplicationLoadBalancer),
    SslPolicy="ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-Ext-2018-06",
    DefaultActions=[elb.Action(
        Type="forward",
        TargetGroupArn=Ref(TargetGroupApp)
    )]
))

ListenerCertificate = t.add_resource(elb.ListenerCertificate(
    "ListenerCertificate",
    Certificates=elb.Certificate(
            CertificateArn="",
            ),
    ListenerArn=Ref(Listener)
    ))
```

How can i add `certificate` in listner and `listnercertificate`,

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to add an existing certificate to a listener - you've listed both of them, but you should really only need one of them.  Also, I'm assuming you need to create the certificate.  This shows how, and it show both ways of attaching that cert. One thing to keep in mind - there's a manual step to approving a certificate creation, even when it's created in CloudFormation, so you'll need to keep an eye on the approval request in your email:

```
from troposphere.certificatemanager import Certificate
# First create the certificate if it doesn't already exist

cert = t.add_resource(
    Certificate(
        "MyCert",
        DomainName="example.com",
    )
)

# Now you can add it to the load balancer directly/inline
Listener = t.add_resource(elb.Listener(
    "Listener",
    Certificates=elb.Certificate(
        CertificateArn=cert.Ref(),
    ),
    Port="443",
    Protocol="HTTPS",
    LoadBalancerArn=Ref(ApplicationLoadBalancer),
    SslPolicy="ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-Ext-2018-06",
    DefaultActions=[elb.Action(
        Type="forward",
        TargetGroupArn=Ref(TargetGroupApp)
    )]
))


# Or you can add it to an existing Listener with this resource
ListenerCertificate = t.add_resource(elb.ListenerCertificate(
    "ListenerCertificate",
    Certificates=elb.Certificate(
            CertificateArn=cert.Ref(),
            ),
    ListenerArn=Ref(Listener)
    ))
```

If you already have a certificate, then you don't need the first step to create it - instead just provide the arn (you can find it in the dashboard) as the argument, rather than `cert.Ref()`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I haven't created any `certificate` already I have to create one first. It is being a little bit confusing around hear, 

```ertificate = t.add_resource(
    elb.Certificate(
        'Certificate',
        DomainName='x.x.com',
        DomainValidationOptions=[
            DomainValidationOption(
                DomainName='x.x.com',
                ValidationDomain='x.x.com',
            ),
        ],
        Tags=[
            {
                'Key': 'tag-key',
                'Value': 'tag-value'
            },
        ],
    )
)```
Which way i should use?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue you're having right now?  Can you explain what it is that is confusing you?  I gave an example of creating a certificate in my example above using the certificatemanager Certificate.  The elb.Certificate isn't a Resource, it's a Property that links an ELB to a created certificate.  You can see my use of that in the example as well, here:

Comment: ```    Certificates=elb.Certificate(
        CertificateArn=cert.Ref(),
    ),
```

Comment: Yeah! That worked now--- But in Status it is still in `Pending validation` is there anything else we need to add or specify

Comment: From my original post:

One thing to keep in mind - there's a manual step to approving a certificate creation, even when it's created in CloudFormation, so you'll need to keep an eye on the approval request in your email

Basically you have to approve the certificate manually, and usually that's through an email.  I think you can possibly do that through the certificate manager portal as well, but I"m not sure.

Comment: Yeah,  for that i am creating a new certificate manually and will add to the listener, Certificate varification will need a hosted zone under the route53 DNS, so i have to create that first. thanks for your help